# Text Replacement Using RE - Allow The First Occurance, Replace The Rest

Tags: python, replace, python-re

I am looking for some thoughts on how I would be able to accomplish these tasks:

- Allow the first occurrence of a problem_word, but ban any following uses of it and the rest of the problem words.
- No modifications to the original document (.txt file). Only modify for print().
- Keep the same structure of the email. If there are line breaks, or tabs, or weird spacings, let them keep their integrity.

Here is the code sample:

```
import re

# Sample email is "Hello, banned1. This is banned2. What is going on with
# banned 3? Hopefully banned1 is alright."
sample_email = open('email.txt', 'r').read()


# First use of any of these words is allowed; those following are banned
problem_words = ['banned1', 'banned2', 'banned3']


# TODO: Filter negative_words into overused_negative_words
banned_problem_words = []
for w in problem_words:
    if sample_email.count(f'\\b{w}s?\\b') > 1:
        banned_problem_words.append(w)


pattern = '|'.join(f'\\b{w}s?\\b' for w in banned_problem_words)


def list_check(email, pattern):
    return re.sub(pattern, 'REDACTED', email, flags=re.IGNORECASE)


print(list_check(sample_email, pattern))
# Result should be: "Hello, banned1. This is REDACTED. What is going on with
# REDACTED? Hopefully REDACTED is alright."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `repl` argument of `re.sub` can take a function that takes a match object and returns the replacement string.  Here is my solution:

```py
import re

sample_email = open('email.txt', 'r').read()

# First use of any of these words is allowed; those following are banned
problem_words = ['banned1', 'banned2', 'banned3']

pattern = '|'.join(f'\\b{w}\\b' for w in problem_words)

occurrences = 0

def redact(match):
    global occurrences
    occurrences += 1
    if occurrences > 1:
        return "REDACTED"
    return match.group(0)

replaced = re.sub(pattern, redact, sample_email, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(replaced)
```

(As a further note, `string.count` doesn't support regex, but there is no need to count)

Comment: Thanks for the answer; it works! Now I just have to figure out how it works. I appreciate the insight - cheers!